# creating stock returns from prices in f#

Tags: f#

I have log stock prices as an array in F#

```
let stockprice= Array.zip D12 index |> Array.map (fun (a,b) -> a+b) |> Array.map(fun x -> log(x))
```

However, I cannot figure out how to turn the stock prices to returns, by dividing Pt by Pt-1. Following code does not work:

```
let myreturn= stockprice.diff(1)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on the question, but I guess you're after `array |> Seq.ofArray |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.map (fun (f,s) -> s / f)`. At least until F# 4.0 is released and there's uniform API for all collections, then there *probably* will be `Array.pairwise`. :)

Comment: @İrem Erten, I don`t understand your question, but maybe you rewrite this code:                                                                                                          let stockprice = Array.map2(fun a b -> log(a+b)) D12 index

Comment: Have a look at Deedle time series library: http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/series.html#Shifting-and-differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand my comment - the Deedle library has been designed to do this and the [Shifting and differences](http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/series.html#Shifting-and-differences) section in the time series documentation is pretty much what you need.

If you have a series `ts`, you can calculate the returns by subtracting a shifted series (which is what `Series.diff` does) and then dividing this:

```
(ts - Series.shift 1 ts) / ts   // Subtracting & dividing
(Series.diff 1 ts) / ts         // Even nicer :-)
```